# How to get and split value of the input field in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have and input search field where I can search for make or/and model of the vehicle and then I want to search depending on that term.

But the problem is how can I split make from model if some makes have more than one word in the name and some only one.

My code is as follows:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search make or model" id="search" />
<button type="submit" id="btn-submit">Search</button>
```

And javascript:

```
$("#btn-submit").on("click", function(e){
    let make_model = $("#search").val()
    let make = make_model.split(/ +/)[0]
})
```

If I search for make that has one word and model which has one word I can split the string and use the first value as make and the second one as model. Just like in my example.

Thus if I search for `Audi A5` I can get make and model as follows:

```
let make = "Audi A5".split(/ +/)[0]
let model = "Audi A5".split(/ +/)[1]
```

But the problem is if I search for for example for `Alfa Romeo Giulietta` or something like that. How can I then split the string and get correct make and correct model.

If I have the list of all makes, can I somehow compare searched term and check if the make has more than two words?

Any idea?

[Here is the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/n5oswr0b/2/)

```js
const all_makes = ['Alfa Romeo', 'Aston Martin', 'Audi', 'Volkswagen', 'Volvo']

$(function() {
  $("#btn-submit").on("click", function(e) {
    let make_model = $("#search").val()
    let make = make_model.split(/ +/)[0]
    console.log(make)
  });
});
```

```css
#search {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Search make or model" id="search" />
<button type="submit" id="btn-submit">Search</button>
```

Comment: I guess you mean brand and not "make"?

Comment: @DoubleVoid Yes.

Comment: Why not use a lookup table.

Comment: Why don't you first explain your use case, ie. what you are trying to achieve? The posted code doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Okay, since you only have one input field you will not be able to distinguish between brand and model. You can establish something like a tag based search or lookup table.

Comment: As someone who has worked in the automotive software industry for 7 years, do not split a string into Make, Model, and Trim. While it works for Audi A7, it does not for Land Rover Range Rover (Land Rover being the make and Range Rover being the model) or many other complex examples. You’re going to want to normalize your data and use tables of the normalized data. Alternatively you could purchase normalized data about vehicles from a 3rd party like Blackbook (who I am not affiliated with).

Comment: Another tip since you’re trying to make a text search based on user input, know that people WILL use it wrong. Your placeholder says “make or model”. That to me means type “Ford” or “Focus”, but not “Ford Focus”. Also, people WILL add other stuff like year, fuel type, drive train, transmission, etc into the textbox. They may even try to do ranges like “2010-2015 Ford Focus”. Or they’ll typo the whole thing. These are things you need to consider. You should send the value of the text as is and deal with it server side using what will be a TON of code to work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the list of brands to make a regular expression that can make the split:

```js
const all_makes = ['Alfa Romeo', 'Aston Martin', 'Audi', 'Volkswagen', 'Volvo'];
const regex = new RegExp(`(${all_makes.join('|').replace(' ', '\\s+')}|\\S+)\\s*(.*)`, "i");

$(function() {
  $("#btn-submit").on("click", function(e) {
    let make_model = $("#search").val();
    let [_, make, model] = make_model.match(regex);
    console.log("make =", make);
    console.log("model =", model);
  });
});
```

```css
#search {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Search make or model" id="search" />
<button type="submit" id="btn-submit">Search</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple split on spaces won't cut it - you'll have to look for instances of all the makes in your user's string. You can coerce to lowercase to let users be a little sloppy.

Then you'd take the matching make, split the string after it, trim the result, and use it as the model.

If you have a list of all makes, it's probably easier and less likely to result in user error to have them pick from the list.

Answer (score 0):

As i assume, you want to console the brand name in your case the make variable.

So checking if the model is present as a substring of array element. If the substring exists, print the substring.

Also note that the search is **case sensitive**

**Sample input**

Audi A5

**Sample Output**

Audi

**Sample input**

Alfa Romeo Giulietta

**Sample Output**

Alfa Romeo

```js
const all_makes = ['Alfa Romeo', 'Aston Martin', 'Audi', 'Volkswagen', 'Volvo']

$(function() {
  $("#btn-submit").on("click", function(e) {
    let make_model = $("#search").val()
    let make = make_model.split(/ +/)[0]
    var el = all_makes.find(a => a.includes(make));
    console.log(el)
  });
});
```

```css
#search {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Search make or model" id="search" />
<button type="submit" id="btn-submit">Search</button>
```